# Pronouns in 2 Thes 2:1

Tags: 2-thessalonians, rapture

In 2 Thes 2:1, the sentence structure is TSKS for “coming” and “gathering” (2Th 2:1 …τῆς παρουσίας…καὶ…ἐπισυναγωγῆς). Wallace points out that because it’s impersonal the Granville Sharp Rule really doesn’t apply there showing the two nouns are referring to the same event/time.

> Now we beseech you, brethren, by the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ, and by our gathering together unto him, [2 Thessalonians 2:1 KJV]

My question concerns the pronouns there. ἡμῶν is used before both nouns. Is there any rule with pronouns that is similar to Granville Sharp where having the pronouns occur before both nouns in the same case makes them apply to 2 separate events? For example if only one pronoun was used with the first noun but not the second noun connected with kai, would that indicate they refer to the same thing?

Comment: Welcome to SE-BH. I have edited simply to show the text in discussion and to show how highlighting of quotations is done. Please feel free to rollback if you wish. Up-voted +1. The literal is 'the coming (YLT says 'presence') of the Lord of us, Jesus Christ, and the gathering together unto him' [EGNT- Englishman's Greek New Testament].

Comment: @ Robb - For a similar dilemma concerning Granville-Sharpe see BH.SE #85587 concerning its application to Titus 2:13.  TSKS seems to have very narrow parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the Greek (surprisingly for Paul) of 2 Thess 2:1, is quite simple.  Let me translate this very literally, using the same word order:

> We implore now you, brothers, concerning the advent of the Lord of us, Jesus
> Christ, **and** our gathering-together unto Him, ...

Note that "Jesus Christ" is in apposition to the title "Lord of us"; ie, another name/title for the same person.  Further note that "brother" is also in apposition to "you".

Thus, the text of 1 Thess 2:1 is saying this, with my point-form set out to make it clearer:

> We implore you brothers concerning:
>
> 1. the advent of the Lord us, Jesus Christ,
> 2. **and** our gathering-together unto Him, ...

That is, Paul is clearly stating that the advent (coming and presence) of the Lord Jesus Christ is the time when we will be gathered together unto Him.  The beseeching then concerns V2 where Paul is begging them "*not to be easily disconcerted or alarmed by any spirit or message or letter seeming to be from us ...*"

**TSKS Rule**

Strictly speaking the TSKS rule (a refinement of the Granville Sharp rules - see D B Wallace, Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics, page 271ff) applies only to personal nouns and titles of a person.  Thus it does not apply to abstract nouns such as "coming" and "gathering", despite the fact that both are genitive feminine singular in this case.  However, IF it did apply, it would provide the same conclusion as above - both apply to the same event, ie (1) the advent of Jesus Christ and (2) our gathering together unto Him, would be the same event.

Comment: Do the pronouns carry any additional weight to the discussion? For example, if Paul had left out the second pronoun, making it, ”the advent of our Lord, Jesus Christ, and gathering together to Him.” Would that have made the connection stronger, to refer to the same event, or are the pronouns irrelevant to that?

Comment: @Robb - I do not believe it would have made a difference.